# Should I enable or disable Prefetch/SuperFetch with my new SSD?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, superfetch, prefetch

I recently got a new Samsung SSD. It comes with software called "Samsung Magician".

Basically it lets you configure things with your new SSD. I'm really confused about Prefetch/SuperFetch though.

This is an image of the "General overview":

[image]

When I click more info, it says this:

> Windows stores common device drivers and applications in main memory
> in order to improve performance. Because SSDs have very fast access
> times, this feature is no longer necessary. In addition to taking up
> extra storage space, this feature requires frequent read/write
> operations, and is not recommended for use with an SSD.

However, I'm not sure if the "Deactivate" button deactivates the features that are bad or deactivates stopping them.

So, my question is **should SSDs have prefetc/superfetch enabled?**

Comment: I turned it off in Magician, then disabled Prefetch in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters`. Afterwards, I emptied the Prefetch folder—there's no need for it anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 8 [will skip SSDs](https://web.archive.org/web/20201021001754/https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Disabling-Hibernation-Superfetch-onboard-VGA#time=05m50s), so NEVER change the start type of the Suprfetch service in Windows 8.

Comment: Any explanation for why this is so important that you had to write "NEVER" in all-caps? Your link is broken, BTW.

Comment: @DonJoe I think its a little over-dramatic.   There is no benefit to SuperFetch in modern systems with SSDs.  Since they have no seek time, SuperFetch will always end up with cache misses.  Why take time to look for something in advance, when you can have it instantly?

Answer (score 6):

Samsung Magician has some translation imperfections, which makes some settings in Samsung Magician hard to understand (incomprehensible), especially in OS Optimization – Advanced tab.
An easy way to understand how buttons in Samsung Magician Advanced tab work is to enable hidden system files, go to the root of system C drive, and look at creation and deletion of hiberfil.sys file when Hibernation Mode is activated or deactivated in Samsung Magician Advanced tab.

1. You can Apply Maximum Performance, Maximum Capacity, Maximum Reliability tabs and see what functions were activated or deactivated in Advanced tab. Advanced tab uses a little bit awkward style by showing the opposite of the current status, i.e. Activate means that currently this feature is deactivated and Deactivate means that the feature is currently activated.
2. Changes that you make in Advanced tab by pressing Activate or Deactivate buttons are instant and don’t require pressing Apply All button. For instance, pressing Activate button of Hibernation Mode instantly creates hiberfil.sys in the root of system C drive and button name is changed to Deactivate. On the other hand, pressing Deactivate button, instantly removes hiberfil.sys from the root of system C drive and button name is changed to Activate.
3. You don’t need to press and you shouldn’t press Apply All button in Advanced tab once you finish manually settings the features, because it changes the values to default ones designed by the developers, for instance it Activates (button name is changed to Deactivate) Hibernation Mode.
4. If the combination of settings that you’ve made in Samsung Magician Advanced tab is the same as predefined modes in Apply Maximum Performance, Maximum Capacity or Maximum Reliability tabs, Current Status: name will be changed from Advanced to that particular mode name.
5. In Samsung Magician Advanced OS Optimization:

"Deactivate" button deactivates Prefetch / Superfetch.

"Activate" button activates Prefetch / Superfetch.

For SSDs Prefetch / Superfetch should be disabled.

Here is how you can check that the Superfetch is really disabled in Windows:
Open Run dialog (Win + R) - Type services.msc + Enter to open the Services Manager - Scroll down to Superfetch service - Double-click on it to open it Properties box - The startup type should be Disabled.

Example showing how to interpret Samsung Magician Advanced tab settings:

[image: Magician]

Buttons are showing the opposite status of the current state.  Clicking the button will set it to the state that it is showing. Currently the settings shown in the image mean this:

Hibernation Mode:            OFF

Indexing Service:            OFF

Prefetch:                    OFF

Write Cache Buffer:          ON

Write-Cache Buffer Flushing: ON

Answer (score 4):

In Samsung Magician 4.4 Advanced OS Optimization: 
**"Deactivate" button deactivates Prefetch / Superfetch** 
**"Activate" button activates Prefetch / Superfetch**

So for SSD Prefetch / Superfetch should be disabled.

Here is how you can check that the Superfetch is really disabled in Windows:

- Open Run dialog (Win + R)
- Type services.msc + Enter to open the
  Services Manager
- Scroll down to Superfetch service
- Double-click on it to open it Properties box
- The startup type should be Disabled

Answer (score 3):

According to [Intel](http://download.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/newusersguide.pdf) you should disable Superfetch and not defrag your SSD; OCZ [also says this](http://ocz.com/consumer/ssd-guide/ssd-faqs).

There are reasons for this:

- Defragmentation reduces the life of the drive for no peformance gain.
- Superfetch was essentially [invented because hard drives are slow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefetcher). SSD's pretty much eliminate this reason.

Comment: Although the SuperFetch benefit will not be as large with SSD as with a HDD, you will still benefit by having SuperFetch on - even when using an SSD. It is also important to ensure it is on if you have both SSD and HDD (e.g. user profile, documents, Outlook archive, dozens of gigabytes of games on the spinning platter). Windows 7 mistakenly would turn off SuperFetch if the primary disk was solid state. Windows 8 got smarter about leaving SuperFetch on. And yes, SuperFetch is still useful for caching in RAM things stored on a SSD.

Comment: "
Oops!
The page you are looking for may have a new location, or is no longer available.
"

Answer (score 0):

Late models SSd drives in Win7 or 8 don't need to be fiddled with. Windows does it. Also - after talking to OCZ representative - new model SSD's nowadays don'y need anything turned off (exceprt maybe indexng)